# 'Allow Multiple Downloads' on browser popup using Selenium Webdriver C# with Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to download multiple files using C# and selenium web driver. However, if I download more than one file I get a pop-up window, asking me to confirm I wish to allow multiple downloads of files.
How do I click  'Allow'?

I have tried

`driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`

and also jsexecutor

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

but neither of these work.

I just want to click Allow on the popup to continue my test.

Comment: Look at what the popups path is, and then use Selenium to select it and the Accept/Ok button

Comment: Thanks, all I want to do is click the Allow button, is there no simple way of doing that?

Comment: Yes, store the XPath for it and then use Selenium to grab the element and Click() it

Comment: Yes but I can inspect the element for it, as it is a pop up window.

Comment: Yea just inspect it, it will be generic.

Comment: sorry I meant I can't inspect as it is a different window